# What is the recommended way to build an apt mirror with multiple versions of packages?

Tags: apt-mirror

We have a local apt mirror built with `apt-mirror` and it's working nicely, but since it considers valid only the latest version of every package, if there's the need to downgrade one of them (because of a regression or whatever) we can't rollback to the previous one, we can only go back to the first version available.

For example, we are having a problem with Thunderbird 24.5.0 and we'd like to go back to 24.4.0, but:

```
$ apt-cache show thunderbird | grep Version
Version: 1:24.5.0+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1
Version: 11.0.1+build1-0ubuntu2
```

What is the recommended way to build an apt mirror that keeps more versions of the same package available?

Comment: We build our own apt repo using `dpkg-scanpackages` which has the `--multiversion` option for this exact behavior. Perhaps pursuing this route might be an option.

Comment: Another option might be [aptly](http://www.aptly.info/) which might help here.

Comment: @Patrick: I tried manually "patching" Packages.gz and Packages.bz2 merging the output from `dpkg-scanpackages` last week, but then I had problems with unmatching hashes... I think it could work given some more time, but I was wondering if there's a less manual solution. Thanks though!

Comment: @sr_: I had investigated aptly before posting and it looked like it would "fit the bill", but I was hoping it could be done without switching away from apt-mirror. I'll wait to see if some other solution will crop up, and then I'll try aptly :) Thanks!